# update table id with related ID from other table

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sql-order-by, rows

I'm having trouble updating a table in sql.
I have two tables.

Systemobject table:

> Id SystempointID
>
> 1   NULL
>
> 2   NULL
>
> 3   NULL

SystemPoint table:

> Id othercolumn
>
> 11   testpoint
>
> 12   testpoint2
>
> 13   testpoint 3

I need to update the systemobject table with the systempoint Id. They need to match in order. This is how my SystemObject table has to be:

Systemobject table:

> Id SystempointID
>
> 1   11
>
> 2   12
>
> 3   13

I have 500+ of these Ids, so i want to know which query i have to use to fill my systemobject table with the systempoint Id automatically. the highest system point id has to match the highest systemobject id.
I have tried this code:

```
UPDATE [demo].[dbo].[SystemObject]
SET SystemPointId = (SELECT [demo].[dbo].[SystemPoint].[Id] FROM [demo].[dbo].[SystemPoint] 
WHERE SystemPoint.Id = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM [demo].[dbo].[SystemPoint]))
```

When i use this code i get one value (the highest systempoint id) on all of the rows in my systemobject column. I only want to fill in rows that have the value NULL so that i don't override my values that are already filled in.

Comment: Do you want to fill Max value or the unique values.

Comment: max value @ankit Bajpai

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
UPDATE [demo].[dbo].[SystemObject]
SET SystemPointId = (SELECT [demo].[dbo].[SystemPoint].[Id] FROM [demo].[dbo].[SystemPoint]) 
WHERE [demo].[dbo].[SystemObject].SystemPointId IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thanks, the NULL values get filled in now. But i still get the same systempoint id. I get 13 three times instead of 11 12 13

Comment: Ohhh. This means you need unique values all the time.

Comment: thanks but i get the error: 'Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.'